# Unable to Paste my selection in VBA in a particular Range

Tags: vba, excel, copy

```
Private Sub Daily_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:P1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This throws up a  1004 error saying 'Application - Defined/Object Defined' error

I tried to change line 4 to

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This works. I need to know why the first piece of code won't work

Comment: When i change line 4 to Sheets("Sheet2"). Select

Answer (score 0):

Better dont use `Select`.

Easy way to copy something:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:P1")
```

Edit: or with `Select`:

```
Sub Daily_Click()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:P1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: And what exactly would the error in my code be? I am still unable to figure that out

Comment: @bhavya: you try Select Range `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:P1").Select` when other sheets are activate